# APi de geolocalizacion

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con NodeJS y quiero agregar geoocalización, pero al querer buscar una dirección me aparece este error como puedo solucionarlo?, por favor

**Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account**

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español, recuerda darte una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código para que podamos reproducir el escenario.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida a la comunidad,

Esto se debe a que desde hace unos meses google cambió las políticas de uso de sus APIs, por tal motivo ahora es necesario tener un api key con el que puedes hacer las peticiones a la misma.

Debes crear una cuenta en google cloud, generar la key y luego hacer las peticiones con dicha key.

Por pasos sería:

1. Crear la cuenta de google cloud platform: https://cloud.google.com/ luego de crearla entrar a la consola https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Habilitar la api de geocoder: en el menu de navegación a la izquierda seleccionar
   "apis y servicios", luego en la pantalla arriba aparece un boton que indica "habilitar apis y servicios" pulsas ese boton, en el buscador colocas "Geocoder" y abajo te sale, pulsas sobre la misma y te aparecerá el botón "habilitar" pues lo habilitas.
3. Crear una credencial para la api: De nuevo ir a "apis y servicios" en el menú principal y luego a "credenciales", pulsar sobre "crear credenciales" y luego "clave de api", se te creará una clave de api. Ya acá puedes usarla, por ejemplo así:
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=buenos%20aires%20caballito&key=TUCLAVEAPI (reemplazar TUCLAVEAPI con el key que acabas de generar)

El tema es que si alguien obtiene esa key la puede utilizar y abusar de la misma (recuerda que a partir de una cantidad de peticiones google comenzará a cobrar, tienes que leer ya que no recuerdo cómo es el monto de las cuotas, pero es una cantidad alta de peticiones que puedes hacer, ésto es más para que no se abuse pero para desarrollos pequeños no hay tanto problema), para restringir un poco la key que acabas de crear tienes que pulsar sobre el boton de edición que se muestra a la derecha de la key (es un lapiz), allí colocas un nombre si ya no lo tiene y abajo veras dos pestañas, la primera "restricciones de aplicación" que es en la cual indicarás de cual dirección ip se puede utilizar la key o una url por ejemplo https://midominio.com/*, en la segunda pestaña "restricciones de api" indicarás qué apis se pueden usar con esa clave, en ésta seleccionas "Geocoding Api".

Con ésto ya tendrías el key asegurado, recuerda que el key debes resguardarlo, por lo que no lo debes subir a plataformas como github si es un repositorio público.

Cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Saludos!